# For arbitrary random variable $Z$, prove $P(\lvert Z1_{B^{c}}\lvert > \epsilon) \leq P(B^{c})$?

Tags: probability, convergence, asymptotics

This question is asked to understand proof of Lemma 9.15 from [Keener](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-93839-4).

For arbitrary random variable $Z$, show that

$$P(\lvert Z1_{B^{c}} \lvert > \epsilon) \leq P(B^{c})$$

for event $B$ and its complement $B^{c}$.

I tried applying Markov's inequality but that does not seem to give the desired probability bound

$$P(\lvert Z1_{B^{c}}\lvert > \epsilon) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[\lvert Z1_{B^{c}}\lvert]}{\epsilon}$$

Note: previous version asked about sequence of events $B_{n}$ and arbitrary random variables $Z_{n}$.

Answer (score 2):

If $B_n$ holds then $|Z_n 1_{B_n^c}| = 0 \not > \epsilon$. This means that $B_n \subset \{|Z_n 1_{B_n^c}| \not > \epsilon\}$. The rest should be easy to deduce.

Answer (score 0):

A nonverbal version of the hint/answer provided by @passerby51 (+1):
$$\begin{align}P(\lvert Z_{n}1_{B_{n}^{c}} \lvert > \epsilon) &=P(|Z_n1_{B_{n}^c}|>\epsilon|B_n)P(B_n)+P(|Z_n1_{B_{n}^c}|>\epsilon|B_n^c)P(B_n^c)\\&=P(0>\epsilon|B_n)P(B_n)+P(|Z_n|>\epsilon|B_n^c)P(B_n^c)\\&=P(|Z_n|>\epsilon|B_n^c)P(B_n^c)\\&\leq P(B_n^c)\end{align}$$

Though I don't see any use of $P(B_n)\rightarrow 1$.

Comment: Thank you. After seeing your answer, the condition that $P(B_{n}) \rightarrow 1$ is indeed unnecessary for the result (and the question modified accordingly).

To complete the proof started by @passerby51:

\begin{align*}
P(B_{n}) \leq P(\lvert Z_{n}1_{B_{n}^{c}} \lvert \leq \epsilon) &\implies 1 - P(B_{n}) \geq 1 - P(\lvert Z_{n}1_{B_{n}^{c}} \lvert \leq \epsilon)\\
&\implies P(B_{n}^{c}) \geq P(\lvert Z_{n}1_{B_{n}^{c}} \lvert > \epsilon)
\end{align*}

Comment: Also want to add that $B_{n} \subset \{\lvert Z_{n}1_{B_{n}^{c}} \lvert \leq \epsilon \}$ is true because $\lvert Z_{n}1_{B_{n}^{c}} \lvert \leq \epsilon$ can be true even if $B_{n}^{c}$ holds.

Comment: @CalvinChi, yes $P(B_n) \to 1$ is unnecessary for the inequality.